# Связка RxJava + Room + MVP где вызывать асинхронный запрос к БД?

Tags: java, android, rxjava, mvp, room

Подскажите пожалуйста наилучшую практику обращения к БД в паттерне MVP в связке RxJava + Room + MVP под Андроид. Где правильно вызывать асинхронный запрос через Rx к БД ? В презентере или в модели?

1. Если в модели, тогда как возвращать результат запроса презентеру? Коллбеком?
2. Если в презентере, но при этом нужно произвести некие манипуляции с данными, прежде чем отдать их представлению для отображения. Не слишком ли это нагрузит презентер лишней логикой, плюс обработкой данных?

Еще вопрос по поводу строки подключения из примера [developer.android.com/](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html) создания экземпляра db.

```
 AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
    AppDatabase.class, "database-name").build();
```

Данная строка требует контекст, где ее правильнее инициализировать? В представлении, презентере или же модели(не передавать же контекст в модель??) ?

Спасибо за любую помощь!

Comment: Погуглите MVP contract - грубо говоря вам надо писать интерфейсы/контракты, которые инжектируются...

Comment: вообще android architecture components , в который входит и Room, предполагает использование MVVM. то есть все эти LiveData, ViewModel и Room изначально разрабатывались для взаимодействия между собой, а не по MVP

Answer (score 2):

Если отвечать конкретно на первый вопрос, то можно сделать примерно следующим образом.

1. Создается Presenter или же ViewModel в Mvvm для получения итогового результата. В его конструктор передается Interactor или UseCase.
2. Создается Interactor или UseCase для необходимых манипуляций с данными, чтобы не перегружать Presenter или ViewModel. В его конструктор передается Dao.
3. Dao (для доступа к исходным данным). Его нам сгенерирует Room.

Учитывая то, что Room поддерживает Rx при подключении дополнительной зависимости "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$v_room", все будет выглядеть примерно так (сильно упрощенный пример из моего проекта).

```
@Dao // Dao-интерфейс, по которому Room сгенерирует необходимый код.
interface VenueDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM venues")
    fun getVenues(): Single<List<VenueDBModel>>
}

class LoadPinsImpl( // UseCase
    private val venueDao: VenueDao,
    private val ioScheduler: Scheduler // просто RxScheduler, который можно заменять для тестов
) : LoadPins {

    override fun invoke(): Single<List<VenuePin>> =
        venueDao.getVenues()
            .map { /* тут преобразуем VenueDBModel в VenuePin */ }
            .subscribeOn(ioScheduler)

}

class VenuesMapViewModelImpl( // ViewModel, вместо нее может быть Presenter, принципиально сути это не меняет
    private val loadPins: LoadPins
) : VenuesMapViewModel() {

    override fun startViewModel() {
        super.startViewModel()
        loadPins()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(::onLoadPins)
            .bindToLifecycle() // используется для того, чтобы завершать все подписки при завершении работы ViewModel. По сути складывает все Disposables в CompositeDisposable
    }

    private fun onLoadPins(pins: List<VenuePin>) {
        // тут передаем все данные во View
    }
}
```

По поводу инициализации базы данных - да, она требует контекст. Поэтому как правило она будет создаваться в модуле, где находятся все зависимости в единственном экземпляре.

По-хорошему, лучше почитать больше статей на эту тему и посмотреть конкретные примеры.

1. https://github.com/mrsegev/MovieNight - пример готовой прилаги
2. https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture - пример clean architecture и организации кода
3. https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/BasicRxJavaSample - тут много примеров (каждый пример в своей ветке), лучше поизучать сразу несколько

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Т.е. грубо говоря мы в модель в итоге передаем объект Dao для запроса в БД, в презентере ожидаем получение обработанных данных, обработку и манипуляции с данными делаем в модели, ну и дальше презентер взаимодействует с представлением?

Comment: @Anocean, да, все верно. Просто в разных архитектурных подходах все называется чуть по-разному. Где-то это UseCase, где-то Interactor, где-то Model, но бизнес логика находится именно там. Presenter просто отображает полученную и преобразованную оттуда информацию

Comment: Не могли бы свой пример привести еще и на Java? Для тех, кто только начинает на Java и еще не знаком с Kotlin